# Type Casting in C resulting in zero

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, average, division

I have a simple C program where, I type cast two integers into float and then calculate their division. But, the type casting is resulting in zero. Kindly, a little help would be much appreciated.

'''

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

float mean(float sum,float N); 
int main()
{
    int sum = 6;
    int N = 3;
    printf("\nsum: %d\nN: %d",sum,N);
    float m = mean((float)sum,(float)N);
    printf("\nMean: %d",m);
}
return 0;
}

float mean(float sum,float N){
    float m = sum / N;
    return m;
}
```

Here's the Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: Please read documentation about format string especially when to use %d

Comment: `printf("\nMean: %d",m);` --> `printf("\nMean: %f\n",m);`

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: There should be a warning about mismatch of provided parameter for conversion specifier. If you didn't get this, you should turn up your compiler diagnostics level. If there was a warning, don't ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

float mean(float sum,float N); 
int main()
{
    int sum = 6;
    int N = 3;
    printf("\nsum: %d\nN: %d",sum,N);
    float m = mean((float)sum,(float)N);
    printf("\nMean: %f",m);
}
return 0;
}

float mean(float sum,float N){
    float m = sum / N;
    return m;
}
```

`%d` prints an integer in base 10, `%f` prints a floating point value. So, for example if I used

```
printf( "%d, %f\n", 9, 9.8 );
```

The output would be `9, 9.800000`. If you give printf `5.5` but use `%d` I think anything could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion codes following % indicates the type of variable to be displayed.
you are tring to disply a float by using an int convertor.

%f float or double --> Signed floating point
use %f in the `printf` function insted of %d or %i --> Singed decimal integer